# How can I scrape twitter's tweets that go 2 years back by scraping?

Tags: python, twitter

I've been looking into scraping, and I cant manage to scrape twitter searches that date long way back by using python code, i can do it however with an addon for chrome but it falls short since it will only let me obtain a very limited amount of tweets. can anybody point me in the right direction¿

Comment: There's only a certain archive of public tweets.. and why are you scraping and not using the Twitter API, or if you really really want archive data, considering looking at one of its partners schemes?

Comment: I have removed my answer as the API version has changed since I last used it so I don't have any code ready to go (authentification is now required). I have also found that the search API that I was going to suggest only goes back about one week (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). There may be other suitable options here(https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)

Answer (score 2):

I found a related answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6082633/1449045

you can get up to 1500 tweets for a search; 3200 for a particular user's timeline

source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know
see "There are pagination limits"

Here you can find a list of libraries to simplify the use of the APIs, 
in different languages, including python
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Answer (score 1):

You can use [snscrape](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape). It doesn't require a Twitter Developer Account it can go back many years.